# Change event for a form field in ngx-formly

Tags: angular, ngx-formly

Scenario - I would like to get the present field value, previous field value and fieldId whenever a particular field loses focus and call an API to perform some validations at the backend

**html**

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <formly-form [form]="form" [model]="model" [fields]="fields">
  </formly-form>
</form>
```

**ts**

```
fields: FormlyFieldConfig[] = [
    {
      key: 'Datepicker',
      type: 'datepicker',
      templateOptions: {
        label: 'Datepicker',
        placeholder: 'Placeholder',
        description: 'Description',
        datepickerOptions: {
          dateChange: (field, $event) => {
            console.log(field)
            console.log($event)
          },
        },
      },
    },
  ];
```

From the above example, say if I have 20 form fields, I would have to implement for each field.
Is there a way to handle focus out from a form field generically without having to implement the change() provided by FormlyFieldConfig?

**I have already tried**

1. form.valuechanges.subscribe() but that doesn't help me since I want this functionality to be enabled only on focus is lost for the field
2. 

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (change)="onChange($event)">
  <formly-form [form]="form" [model]="model" [fields]="fields">
  </formly-form>
</form>
```

Here, I observed that the change event is fired only for the fields of type 'input' in the form and not for other native formly components like 'select' or 'datepicker' or for custom components that have been created

I would like to know if there is a way to get the present field value, previous field value and fieldId generically for all the fields

Comment: Did you a find a solution for this?

Comment: check if this helps
https://github.com/ngx-formly/ngx-formly/issues/3003